# "Теребя", "сочувствуя" — словообразование

Tags: морфемный-разбор, суффиксы, деепричастия

Как образованы слова ***теребя*** и **сочувствуя**?

Я думаю, что оба — бессуффиксным способом.

А как на самом деле?

Comment: "Сочувствуе"-это сочувствует или сочувствуя? Догадайся,мол. сама?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Теребя* — не слово, а форма слова (особая форма глагола — деепричастие), образована от инфинитива ТЕРЕБИТЬ с помощью суффикса *-Я*-. Способ — суффиксальный.

*Сочувствует* — сочувствовать — от глагола *чувствовать* с помощью приставки -СО-. Приставочный способ.

Бессуффиксный:
зелень — от зелёный, рассвет — от рассветать, работа — от работать.

(*Образовано* — краткое причастие, пишется с одной *Н*.)

Answer (score 2):

Деепричастие — это особая форма глагола; деепричастия бывают несовершенного и совершенного вида.
Деепричастия несовершенного вида образуются от глаголов несовершенного вида от   основы НАСТОЯЩЕГО ВРЕМЕНИ по схеме:
(1) теребить — теребит — теребя;
(2) сочувствовать — сочувствует — сочувствуя.
В обоих случаях используется суффикс деепричастия **Я**.

Отметим, что в первом случае перед суффиксом деепричастия **Я**, как и  перед личным окончанием, происходит усечение основы инфинитива на суффикс **И**, а во втором случае глагольный суффикс при спряжении сохраняется, но происходит чередование ОВА/У.